# Customize font size for all the slides in xaringan

Tags: css, xaringan

I'm using Yihui's awesome package `xaringan` to build html slides, and this might be a very simple question for those who are familiar with `xaringan` or css:

I can't figure out how to set the font size of all slides. I tried to define the `font-size` in a customized css, something like `body{font-size: 200%}` or `body{font-size: xx-large}`, and call it in the YAML:

`output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [custom.css]`

Nothing changed. 
I know I can use the `.large` class to change the size of a certain amount of words and use `class: large` at the beginning of a slide to change the body font for the entire page. But, is there a way to avoid pasting `class:large` to every slide I build but set the font size all at once? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The YAML header:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

Try adding the following lines to your Rmd file or put it in your custom.css:

```
<style type="text/css">
.remark-slide-content {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
}
</style>
```

Explanation:

- The above code overrides the default style for remark-slide-content to change font-sizes in your slides under the class `remark-slide-content`, which applies to all the text in your slides.
- During my testing, the padding should also be adjusted accordingly. Experiment it your self.
- Edited: The `!important` rule is not necessary when the slides are not self-contained (i.e. the CSS files were saved separately.)
- Edited again (see comments below):

To set the font-size for one page, first, define a class in the CSS section:

```
.my-one-page-font {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

then add `class: my-one-page-font` before the slide title.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! A couple of issues of using this trick, though: (1) when I added the line in my css, it increased the size of the fonts not only in the `body` but also `h1,2,3`. Is there a way to avoid that? (2) It looks that once I used the trick, I loosed the control for the fonts for separate slides with `class:`. Sorry being annoying but in the practice, I do want to modify the font size for certain single slides. Does removing the `!important` allow that?

Comment: I get it. so you want to be able to change the fonts (for contents) globally as well as changing some pieces locally, right?

Comment: Exactly! Ideally, I hope to use .large{150%} as the default size globally, while using other sizes whenever they are needed.

Comment: Hi, @sammo3182, I've tested & edited my code above. Let me know if it works for you. Forget about the `!important` in my original answer, I misused it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the follow-up, @TC Zhang! The codes work perfectly until I tried to overwrite the font size of a *page*. Your codes allowed me to set the default font size globally and change the size of certain words or sentences using e.g., `.large[the word]`. Both are excellent! On the other hand, is there a possibility for me to overwrite the font size of one certain page? In the default mode of `xaringan`, I could do that by putting `class: small` before the section title of a slide.

Comment: Sure,  define a new class in the css section, for example: `.my-one-page-font {font-size: 40px; }` , then put `class: my-one-page-font` before the section title.

Comment: Works just as I expected. Can't thank you more, @TC Zhang!